# Como recorrer una cadena de caracteres en python, para verificar si el carácter anterior es igual al siguiente?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

tardes o noches. intento hacer un pequeño programita para intentar validar un correo electrónico, aqui esta el codigo:

```
correo = input("Digite la direccion de correo electronico: ");
valido = False;
contadorArroba = 0;
contadorPunto = 0;

for i in correo:
  if(i == '@'):
    contadorArroba += 1
    valido = True
  if(contadorArroba != 1 and contadorPunto < 1):
     valido = False
  if(i == '.'):
    contadorPunto += 1

print(contadorArroba)
print(valido)

if(valido):
   print("el Correro: "+ correo+" es correcto");
else:
   print("direccion erronea");
```

como hago para comprobar si el carácter anterior es igual al carácter siguiente?

Answer (score 1):

Seguro que hay una forma más "pythónica" de hacerlo, pero aquí te dejo una posible solución:

```
cadena = "aabaccdeefg"
for i, caracter in enumerate(cadena):
  if i == 0:
    pass
  else:
    if cadena[i-1] == cadena[i]:
      print "Caracter '%s' repetido en posiciones (%i,%i)" % (caracter, i-1, i)
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Puede acortarse un poco: poniendo `for i, caracter in enumerate(cadena[1:],1):` evitas la condición para saltarse `i==0`.

Answer (score 1):

No sé si más "pythónico", pero sí ciertamente más enrevesado:

```
def letra_duplicada(txt):
    for l1, l2 in zip(txt, txt[1:]):
        if l1 == l2:
          return True
    return False
```

O, en el límite de la brevedad (y de la legibilidad, salvo que te guste la programación funcional):

```
def letra_duplicada(txt):
    return any(l1==l2 for l1,l2 in zip(txt, txt[1:]))
```

:-)